# Brownian Motion with Levy's Characterization 2

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Let W be a $\mathbb{R}$-valued Brownian motion. To prove that $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$, where: $B_t:=W_t-\int_0^t\frac{W_u}{u}du$, is a Brownian Motion with respect to $\mathcal{F}^B$, I showed $[B]_t=t$ and did use Levy's Characterization. 
Is now $B_t$ also a Brownian Motion with w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}^W$ ?
I think showing that $B_t$ is a local $\mathcal{F}^W$-Martingale should be enough. Can i somehow rewrite the equation with Ito's Lemma?